# setting save folder of bittorrent on HDD having an SSD OS

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

OK I have my OS on my SSD and i want to use bittorrent but read that torrents are an ssd killer because of the number of read and write operations. I have an HDD just for file storage.

Question:

If I set the save destination of the torrent to my HDD will that still affect my SSD?

Is there a way to properly set bittorent to only use my hdd?

Comment: Modern SSDs should allow quite a lot of read and write operations. If you just use an occasional torrent then do not worry about it. If you run torrents 24/7 then expect to replace the SSD in a year or 5. (using comments since it is not really an answer to your question).

Comment: Thanks... I've actually though of that but just can't risk it... SSDs are expensive... hopefully it becomes cheaper soon...

Comment: There is no read limit for SSDs and you would have to write the entire capacity of the drive several times per day for over 5 years to approach the write limit for an SSD. You won't come anywhere near this running torrents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your default save directory you should be fine. The large amount of read write operations are to the file being downloaded. As long as you have the save location on the HDD it should not matter that the application launches and reads from the SSD.

Comment: wouldn't it use cache on the ssd?

Comment: if your writing the file to the HDD the disk cache operations for the download should occur there as well.

Comment: Thanks... I'll be considering it.. I'll leave this question open for a while for more opinions and answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is project to combat this file access it's called flashlite and it's avalaible for ctorrent. Unfortunately ctorrent don't support dht and pex. I've already submit the patch to some open-source project but to no avail.